# why are the results of the pwd command and the getcwd() function the same in vim？

Tags: original-vim

I found that using the `:pwd` command is the same as using the `:echo getcwd()` command in the commandline mode of vim. Is pwd the same as cwd? Is there a difference between the two? As follows:

I am currently in the directtory： `/tmp/xyz`

```
$ pwd
/tmp/xyz
```

The `/tmp/xyz` directory structure :

```
$ find /tmp/xyz
/tmp/xyz
/tmp/xyz/dir1
/tmp/xyz/dir1/file1
/tmp/xyz/file
```

I open `/tmp/xyz/file` file via vim in `/tmp/xyz` directory：

```
$ vim /tmp/xyz/file
```

Then I execute  `:pwd` command in the vim window that i just opened:

```
:pwd
```

The result is : `/tmp/xyz`

And then to execute   `:echo getcwd()` command ：

```
:echo getcwd()
```

The result is： `/tmp/xyz`

At this time, it seems that pwd and cwd are the same.

Then i use the same vim window  to open `/tmp/xyz/dir1/file1` ,and to execoute `:pwd` and `:echo getcwd()` commands :

To open `/tmp/xyz/dir1/file1`:

```
:e /tmp/xyz/dir1/file1
```

To execute :pwd ：

```
   :pwd
```

The result is： `/tmp/xyz`

To execute :echo getcwd() :

```
  :echo getcwd()
```

The result is still ： `/tmp/xyz` ; why is the result here not `/tmp/xyz/dir1/` ?

Why is the value of pwd and cwd the same regardless of which file is opened?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but might solve your problem: `:echo resolve(expand('%:p'))`

Answer (score 1):

Yup, they are the same (but `getcwd()` can accepts some arguments so it is useful for Vim scripting), both return the current **working directory**. By default it is the directory where you executed Vim. To change it you need to execute `:cd`.

Comment: Also you can change the current working directory for the current window with `:lcd`.